# embed the string in view flipper ontouch

Tags: android, viewflipper, touch-event

I am creating an application in which i have used four custom view.I have embed  that in the viewflipper now i want to add ontouch event to viewflipper.i have added the ontouchevent but i want that when user touch on the particular position then it will show some text on the canvas which is used by viewflipper.
[image]

I have uploaded the image also can any one help me on this topic .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mention in my question that i am using view.so i have used the invalidate method .

```
Viewflipper .invalidate ();
```

invalidate method force to redraw the view if you want more knowledge then refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28android.graphics.Rect%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use a text View in your ViewFlipper and set its visibility to View.Gone orView.Invisible

when click on your particular zone call

```
myTextView.setText("your text");
myTextView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

hope that idea will help you